# Kotlin sealed class and type inference

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, sealed-class

im using a sealed class to report back success or error to client code:

```
sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

But im stuck getting even the simplest unit test to compile using it:

```
    val error = Result.Error(IOException("message"))
    assertThat(error, instanceOf(Result.Error::class.java))
```

I get the message : Type Inference failed. Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  instanceOf(type : Class<*>) : Matcher!

Looks like im missing something important in Kotlin.

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no problem with your code for me.

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Assert.*
import java.io.IOException

class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun test1() {
        val error = Result.Error(IOException("message"))
        assertTrue(error is Result.Error)
    }

    @Test
    fun test2() {
        val error = Result.Error(IOException("message"))
        assertThat(error , instanceOf(Result.Error::class.java))
    }

    sealed class Result<out T : Any> {
        data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
        data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    }
}
```

Also, I'll suggest you to use the keyword `is` to check if your class is an instance of something in kotlin (like in test1)

Comment: Took my a while to come back here. using assertThat with instanceOf or 'is' makes no difference and may be a matter of choice.

Comment: Using `instanceOf` has a better error message.  It indicates which type was received.  Using `is` just returns a bool and you have to figure out which type was sent.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ::class I prefer this.

`assertThat(result is Result.Error).isTrue()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i was looking in the false API. As im mostly using assertj.
Below code is clean and fluent to read

```
assertThat(result).isInstanceOf(Result.Error::class.java)
```